# Linq Skip and Take function makes the navigation properties null in EF core

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-3.0

I have an IQueryable object which contains a huge number of records. I want to apply pagination on this by using LINQ Skip and Take functions. This is the kind of structure I have and I am using navigation properties using EF core.

```
{
Permission: {
   User: {
    Roles: List<Role>
   }
  }
}
```

LINQ query

```
var permissionQuery = from user in _context.users
                    .Include(x => x.Roles)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.BusinessRole)
                    join permission in _context.Permissions
                    .Include(x => x.PermissionOperations)
                    on user.Id equals permission.UserId
                    select new Entities.Permission
                    {
                        PermissionOperations = permission.PermissionOperations,
                        User = user,
                    };
```

Pagination

```
permissionQuery = permissionQuery.Skip(0).Take(10)
return permissionQuery.ToList() // This makes Roles property null
```

My LINQ query is well constructed and it returns me the result as expected but when I apply pagination, my roles property is getting null which is quite surprising.

Pagination should only filter the records, it should not make the internal properties null. Could anyone please throw some light on this

Comment: Please put your codes here if you want to give clear answers!

Comment: Where is the pagination code?

Comment: You're using a JOIN, not navigation properties. If you used navigation properties you wouldn't have to do that. You don't explain what `PermissionOperations` is, but unless it's a single object, it needs an `Include` too

Comment: PermissionOperations are already included with _context.Permissions. Updated the code here. Yes its a mix of join and nav prop which I can refactor but the problem comes only when I do the pagination. Without pagination I get all the properties mentioned

Comment: Any idea why nested properties are getting null after pagination?